# flutter web calling firebase functions getting internal error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

When I call an httpscallable firebase functions I always get:

```
Error: [firebase_functions/internal] internal
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:33285/dart_sdk.js:5075:11)
at https_callable_web.HttpsCallableWeb.new.call (http://localhost:33285/packages/cloud_functions_web/https_callable_web.dart.lib.js:45:23)
```

This is the code of the callable:

```
 HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1').httpsCallable('listFruit');
 final results = await callable();
 List fruit = results.data;
```

Node.js code:

```
exports.listFruit = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  cors(data, context, () => {
    return ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grapes"]
  });
});
```

I get the same error when I am not authenticated or I am calling a function that doesn't exist.

This is the `index.html` file:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

I can't find latest versions.

How to fix that?

The web error is:

```
"Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/listFruit' from origin 'http://localhost:40423' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."
```

I have enabled cors in firebase functions:

```
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true,
});
```

Comment: if you are calling emulators function the you should use 
 FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west2').useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause is because you specify the region, I fixed it by omitting the region. I answered a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73100153/10294178.

Hope it helps

**===UPDATE===**

The real root cause is the region you specified in the cloud functions and the firebase functions are different, I already update the answer on the link I provided before

Answer (score 0):

As you will see in the [doc for Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), you don't need to use `cors` in a Callable CF.

You return an array, which can be JSON encoded, so you should not encounter any problem with:

```
exports.listFruit = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grapes"];
});
```

Comment: I am still having the cors policy error. I don't know how to fix it.